# VF: ActionStatus not working

Tags: visualforce, actionstatus

I am trying to get an action status to gray out the page while the DML update is in progress. I have had success with this on other pages but I can't get it to work on this one.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Should the actionstatus always go in a particular section of the page code?

```
<apex:page controller="EmpMerge_Controller">

    <style>
        #header {
        color:White;
        text-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        width:80%;
        align:center;
        }
        #nav {
        width:15%;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
        color:black;
        }
        #section {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        }
        .selected {
        color:black;
        }
        .selected:hover {
        color:blue;
        }
    </style> 
    <!-- -->
    <apex:form >
        <div id="section"> 

            <apex:pageblock tabStyle="Employee_Session__c" title="Transfer Details">
                <apex:actionStatus id="tbloading">
                    <apex:facet name="start">
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.50; z-index: 1000; background-color: gray;">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1001; margin: 20% 50%; color:white;">
                            <img src="/img/loading32.gif"/>
                        </div >
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:actionStatus>

                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Current HBS ID:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="New HBS ID:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!empName}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                    <apex:inputField label="HBS ID:" id="pickerHBSID" value="{!emp.Employee__c}" required="true" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!mergeRecords}" title="Transfer" value="Transfer" status="tbloading" >
                    </apex:commandButton>                
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageblock>

            <apex:pageblock tabStyle="Employee_Session__c" title="Records for Transfer">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Sessions" collapsible="false" columns="1">
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!EmpSessions}" var="ES" id="Detail" >
                        <apex:column headerClass="headerClass">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Session Name</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!ES.Name}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerClass="headerClass">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Specialist</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!ES.Specialist__c}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerClass="headerClass">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Created Date</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!ES.CreatedDate}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerClass="headerClass">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Last Modified Date</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!ES.LastModifiedDate}" />
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Tasks" collapsible="false" columns="1"> 
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Tasks}" var="tsk">
                        <apex:column headerClass="headerClass">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.Subject}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerClass="headerClass">
                            <apex:facet name="header">CreatedDate</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.CreatedDate}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerClass="headerClass">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Record ID</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.Id}" />
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageblock>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: FYI, the save button is about 8 lines down from the close of actionstatus

Comment: try re-rendering something some section on the command button, rerender="some component Id"

Comment: Oh hahahahahah wow, yep that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try re-rendering something some section on the command button, `rerender="some component Id"`